# TypeScript "not" function

Tags: typescript, generics, types, functional-programming, typescript-generics

How do I tell TypeScript to connect the parameter type of `fn` above to the parameter type of `...args` below??

```
  /**
   * @template F
   * @param {(...o: Parameters<F>) => boolean} fn
   */
  function not(fn) {
    return (
      /**
       * @param {Parameters<F>} args
       * @returns {boolean}
       */
      (...args) => {
        return !fn(...args);
      }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using JSDoc I guess I'd write it this way:

```
/**
 * @template {any[]} A
 * @param {(...args: A)=>boolean} fn
 */
function not(fn) {
  return (
    /**
     * @param {A} args
     * @returns {boolean}
     */
    (...args) => {
      return !fn(...args);
    });
}
```

The point is to be generic in `A`, the type of `args` instead of in `F` which is presumably a function type.

You can test it:

```
/**
 * @param {string} x
 * @param {number} y
 */
function hmm(x, y) {
  return x.length === y;
}

const notHmm = not(hmm);
notHmm("", 2)
notHmm(123, "") // error!
// --> ~~~
// Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.(2345)
notHmm(); // error!
// Expected 2 arguments, but got 0.(2554)
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?useJavaScript=true#code/PQKhCgAIUgBAXApgWwA4BsCGTIG9MB2AngNoC6AvpAIJQyyqYBOmyeAFAHTfMDmAzgC4aASgC8APgBGAexnpEhKgDMCdYOGUBXAgGN4ASxkFIBGfHaqReKJCaJ4Wpifa3IkUBHff6jFm1xqKj5+N3d6e0dnfjxZeUUCCjDoDW9ILh4mAWtJGzT3SKcTAEJVDM4QkQBuMIpq8CTwTzo4P1Y8fngmAwJeKgAPFoZmdtwCLWQpRCYqInVNHX0jEwALZGR2foAaSCJrXFtC50h+zgVe+BXIMRvdmsbdY07TcwAJdeuXizXkerN4d4bABEQJ2ACYROB-oD2ABGMEAZh2IOswGAkGmTBkTGKTXRAFp8RJIAA-Ml4mhZCaIAjwSAyZSQeBEVCISAAcnGk2m7MgBhi-0gmH4-AMvAImCkCiZMkgbWQDmm9MZzNZHM63V67M47ERABYAKyQ6HrdjVDzozHY3FoyAAUX6rP0iAAJpAwUKqQrafwdlItHTeOZIAAGHVgg0GvUiIA)

In TS that would be

```
function not<A extends any[]>(
  fn: (...args: A) => boolean
) {
  return (
    (...args: A) => {
      return !fn(...args);
    });
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABGOUA8BBRBTAHlbMAEwGdEBDMATwG0BdAPgAoAoRRYMALkSYDoB5AE4BzEjwwBKRAF4GiAEZw4AG2yUW0gN5tEQ7FBBCkrdu36DR4xFNnydZs-sPHEAQk4W+wsZIDcuuwAvv4sQSwsoJCwCIgAFgC2CUy4PCRQQjBgIgA0iFQ8YCAJCthC2rrORki4fGrZUHGyMjL5AeEsEAjpyKgAEkmyvVBMiQmhKFADyQBEM3kATBP9SUwAjAsAzHlz0gD0ezhCQnBCbiwHiAC0V-IAfg8XhxiixYRQiHDAiFBUAA7YRAAciKJTKQMQMDIkwoJBIMBEYHICjUPzgiD+wnICQMZU+31+AOB6Uy2SBfCYWwALABWSQsSbTJj+RCXMonM5PRAAUVwAOg2CIiAWFFeOLAUBIeQUIA+IlQiAADBSFjSaVTJEA)

Comment: I don't want to use `any`, I'm trying to let TypeScript make sure my wrapped function has the same parameter types as the function it wraps.

Comment: Yes, that's what this answer does.  You're not "using `any`" in the sense you might be thinking about.

Comment: Oh, I see what you did, you just extended any[]. Well, that mostly works, except TypeScript tells me that the argument is now optional. So if f takes `string, number`, not(f) takes `string?, number?`

Comment: [That's just how TS-checked JS works](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-checking-javascript-files.html#function-parameters-are-optional-by-default).  Not sure what you want me to do about that.  Actually, [I can't reproduce that](https://tsplay.dev/PmLg4N) so you might want to be specific about your issue (although if it's just how JS-in-TS works then I can't do anything but commiserate with you)

Comment: Turns out that the optional thing was because I used `@type` right before the param, instead of `@param` right before the function, which fixes the wrongl-optional-ness. So your answer is just great.